# Find list of values available in pandas dataframe with binary values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` like following:

```
   session  p1  p2  p3  p4  p5  p6  p7  p8  p9  p10
0        1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1    0
1        2   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1    1
2        3   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1    0
3        4   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0    0
4        5   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1    1
5        6   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0    0
6        7   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1    0
7        8   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1    1
8        9   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0    0
9       10   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1    0
```

And I have list values like following.

```
listvals = ['p1','p5','p9']
```

What I wanted is to get

> 1. "session" numbers where all list values are included
> 2. "session" numbers where at lest two of list values are included
> 3. remaining "session" numbers

Still couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by "all list values are included", you mean that the corresponding columns are 1:

```
>>> df.session[df[listvals].sum(axis=1) == len(listvals)]
0    1
1    2
2    3
4    5 
7    8
Name: session, dtype: int64
>>> df.session[df[listvals].sum(axis=1) >= 2]
0     1
1     2
2     3
4     5
6     7
7     8
9    10
Name: session, dtype: int64
>>> df.session[df[listvals].sum(axis=1) <= 1]
3    4
5    6
8    9
Name: session, dtype: int64
```

Note that this assumes that all the values are either 0 or 1, as the "binary values" in the question makes it seem.  We could use `(df[listvals] != 0).sum(axis=1)` instead if we only know that it's 0 or some nonzero value so that `[0,3,0]` doesn't fool us.

If you wanted the session numbers grouped by the number of included columns, you could use `groupby`, e.g. `df["session"].groupby(df[listvals].sum(axis=1))`.

Comment: :Thanks very much for your explanation! Worked nicely!